# Intel Core i3/i5/i7 Sandy Bridge CPU throttling

Tags: linux, kernel, power-management, cpu-frequency

Intel Sandy-Bridge family i5 Core CPU, running Linux kernel 3.2 (Debian Squeeze/Wheezy), under heavy computation load, does not react to to `cpufreq-set -g powersave` (using acpi_cpufreq module). It is 99.9% time running in turbo mode, although it seems to be somehow throttled automatically, as can be seen in kernel messages (`dmesg`):

```
...
[137547.968129] CPU2: Package temperature/speed normal
[137547.968130] CPU0: Package temperature/speed normal
[137548.124277] CPU2: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 16455155)
[137548.124280] CPU3: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 16455154)
[137548.125289] CPU2: Core temperature/speed normal
[137548.125291] CPU3: Core temperature/speed normal
[137847.287143] CPU2: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 17888019)
[137847.287147] CPU3: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 17888017)
...
```

I'd like to turn this CPU to power-saving mode, or choose the frequency, like with good old cpufreq powersave or userpace cpufreq governors. I wonder, what manual throttling method would work on these CPUs..

Comment: I experience similar problems too, I don't think that really matters, what's your model, X220?

Comment: Sounds like maybe acpi_cpufreq isn't working—in which case userspace governor won't work either. That'd be a BIOS problem, probably.

Comment: warl0ck, it's classified :) CPU model is i5-2520M

Comment: derobert: i think that the acpi_cpufreq module was the only cpufreq driver able to load

Comment: warl0ck: my another issue on this laptop was, that even when idle, fan was relatively loud and power draw ~15W.. even with i195.i915_enable_rc6=7 option.. it was fixed by switching from archlinux to debian (maybe a bug in very recent kernels). now in idle it's silent, ~9W, like in win7.

Answer (score 0):

It is not easily possible to scale down the CPU speed to a certain frequency, but in this blogpost, you find a script to disable turbo-boost: http://notepad2.blogspot.com/2014/11/a-script-to-turn-off-intel-cpu-turbo.html

(This will probably solve the issue for many searchers, that ended up here.)